# align form elements horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am new to this and I have a form in HTML which I would like to have the spaces for the user input aligned. Now my form looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have all textboxes, "Science" dropdown and "Choose Files" button aligned if it's possible.

```html
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("logo.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 50%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
input[type="file"]{
  width:183px;
}
select{
  width:177px;
}
</style>
<!-- The Form Section -->
<div class="w3-green" id="form_section">
  <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
    <h2 class="w3-wide" align="Center"><strong>Přihláška</strong></h2>
    <form align="center" action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
      <label for="fname">Jmeno:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="lname">Příjmení:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="prace">Odkaz na bakalářskou práci:</label>
      <input type="text" id="prace_something" name="prace_something" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="vysoho">Vysoká škola:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vysoho" name="vysoho_skola" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="fname">Studijní obor:</label>
      <input type="text" id="obor" name="obor" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="dropdown">Kategorie v soutěži:</label>
      <select id="kategorie" name="items">
        <option value="science">Science</option>
        <option value="technology">Technology</option>
        <option value="science">Engineering</option>
        <option value="science">Mathematics</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="myfile">Bakalářská práce:</label>
      <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="gdpr" name="gdpr" value="">
      <label for="gdpr"> I agree with GDPR for SWE and Honeywell</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poslat">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, you meant "vertically". The inputs are positioned horizontally and aligned vertically.

Comment: Probably yes. Like the textboxes to be in the same column. Apologize for my english

Comment: You can do it with style css, labels float left and inputs float right. Give labels and inputs width with percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this flexbox solution, which uses `justify-content:space-between`:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
input[type="file"]{
  width:183px;
}
select{
  width:177px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The Form Section -->
<div class="w3-green" id="form_section">
  <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
    <h2 class="w3-wide" align="Center"><strong>Přihláška</strong></h2>
    <form align="center" action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname">Jmeno:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="lname">Příjmení:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="prace">Odkaz na bakalářskou práci:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="prace_something" name="prace_something" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="vysoho">Vysoká škola:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="vysoho" name="vysoho_skola" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="fname">Studijní obor:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" id="obor" name="obor" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="dropdown">Kategorie v soutěži:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <select id="kategorie" name="items">
            <option value="science">Science</option>
            <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="science">Engineering</option>
            <option value="science">Mathematics</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="myfile">Bakalářská práce:</label></div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" id="gdpr" name="gdpr" value="">
          <label for="gdpr"> I agree with GDPR for SWE and Honeywell</label></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poslat"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your reply is very close to what i want. But it displays the form like this: https://pasteboard.co/K62bKfm.png

Comment: @AlexKolydas I think it might be because the width of the screen is too small, or some CSS is interfering with the styling. In any case, could you edit your question to include the CSS? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok i have updated the CSS :) Most of the css contains basically your CSS and isherwood reply CSS

Answer (score 2):

The usual strategy is to make all the labels the same width, or to use a layout grid.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- The Form Section -->
<div class="w3-green" id="form_section">
  <div class="w3-container w3-content w3-padding-64" style="max-width:800px">
    <h2 class="w3-wide"><strong>Přihláška</strong></h2>
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
      <label for="fname">Jmeno:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="lname">Příjmení:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="prace">Odkaz na bakalářskou práci:</label>
      <input type="text" id="prace_something" name="prace_something" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="vysoho">Vysoká škola:</label>
      <input type="text" id="vysoho" name="vysoho_skola" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="fname">Studijní obor:</label>
      <input type="text" id="obor" name="obor" value=""><br><br>
      <label for="dropdown">Kategorie v soutěži:</label>
      <select id="kategorie" name="items">
        <option value="science">Science</option>
        <option value="technology">Technology</option>
        <option value="science">Engineering</option>
        <option value="science">Mathematics</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="myfile">Bakalářská práce:</label>
      <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple><br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="gdpr" name="gdpr" value="">
      <label for="gdpr"> I agree with GDPR for SWE and Honeywell</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poslat">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This aligns the text perfectly. But i would like the texboxes to be aligned. Here is a screenshot of what it shows : https://pasteboard.co/K62dIyt.png

Comment: It shows what you see in the live demo above. You can't expect us to debug what we can't see.